# How to decode Piexif XPKeywords?

Tags: python, jpeg, decoding, piexif

I've been using Piexif to add tags to Jpeg images and that has been going fine.
Now I wanted to read the tags an image has and I'm running into a problem. I gave an image the tags (Tag1, Tag2, Tag3) and using this code I'm supposed to be able to read those keywords:

```
exif_dict = piexif.load(path)
keywords = exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.XPKeywords]
```

What it returns is this:
(255, 254, 84, 0, 97, 0, 103, 0, 49, 0, 59, 0, 84, 0, 97, 0, 103, 0, 50, 0, 59, 0, 84, 0, 97, 0, 103, 0, 51, 0)
I understand that (84, 0, 97, 0, 103) stands for the word **Tag**, but I have no idea what kind of encoding this is.

Does someone happen to know what encoding Piexif uses or just recognizes it in general?

Comment: These first 2 bytes indicate this is a [UTF-16-LE string](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode_encodings.html#byte-order-marks-bom). It probably gets mentioned somewhere in the piexif documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might've been overthinking it. We can simply use something like this to return the numbers to ASCII characters.

```
tags = ""
for num in exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.XPKeywords]:
    tags += chr(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of the accepted answer this is safer due to the encoding used to store the xpkeywords:

```
keywordsraw = exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.XPKeywords]
keywords = str(bytes(keywordsraw), "utf-16le")
```